# newline after cat multiple txt files

Tags: bash, newline, cat

I'm trying to use bash to read data from several one line text files, each in its own directory, and spit them out into one master file, each on a new line.

The data of my input file is structured like so ;

```
Store# online backoffice win7
```

I'm looping through each directory with find and cat the file contents to a variable. The problem is I can't seem to get each pass to put the data on a newline. Here is my code;

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find all sites
stores=$(find /home/sites*/ -maxdepth 0)


for store in $stores; do
  final=${final}$(cat ${store}\processors.txt)"\n"
done

printf "${final}" > ~/master.txt
```

What I get in the master file is

```
Store# online backoffice win7Store# online backoffice win7
```

Comment: It seems you only want `cat /home/sites*/processors.txt > ~/master.txt`. Are you reading your file `master.txt` on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, reading it on a windows machine.

Comment: You might need to transform the unix newlines into dos newlines with the `unix2dos` utility, or to set your editor to handle unix newlines (if you have a decent editor, it should be doable).

Comment: You should quote `${final}` when adding new text to it or you lose all newlines.Also you are losing the newline from the shell command anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your script by this one-liner:

```
find /home/sites* -name "processors.txt" -exec cat {} + > ~/master.txt
```

As you will be reading in a windows machine, you may want to insert return carriage at the end of line:

```
 find /home/sites* -name "processors.txt" -exec cat {} + | sed -e 's/$/\r/' > ~/master.txt
```

Comment: find /home/sites* -name "processors.txt" -exec cat {} + > ~/master.txt worked. Thank you!